# linux insert file content before string match

Tags: linux, awk, sed

Hi I am having some problems with this.

I have a original file:

```
$cat original.txt
User has access to the system
```

And a second file with the content I want to add to the original file:

```
$cat toAdd.txt
Anna
```

The result should be as follows:

```
$cat original.txt
User Anna has access to the system
```

I tried with several options such as:

```
sed '/has/e cat toAdd.txt' original.txt
```

but it is not working :-(

Please help!!

Comment: Suggested solution does not work in this case.

Comment: Explain why the suggested solution does not work then!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Through awk,

```
$ awk 'FNR==NR{var=$0; next}{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++){if($i=="has"){$i=var" "$i}}}1' toAdd.txt original.txt
User Anna has access to the system
```

Comment: Hi, thanks! however that was only a simple example. I would prefer a solution where I can pass the pattern to match, and not only based on its position on the string. In this example "has" would be the pattern to match, and then insert the text from file before of it.

Comment: Oh, did you try the answer in the original question?

Comment: yes, i tried i.e. sed '/has/ r toAdd.txt' original.txt, but it does not work

Comment: @MrTeleBird try my update..